# Returning ternary within lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, ternary-operator

I have a `Func<IList<string>>`which I want to assign to a property.

I want to check if there is anything in the list, and if there is then I want to insert an item at the start and then return the list.

If there isn't I just want to return a list.

It seems I can do it like:

```
Errors = new Func<IList<string>>(() =>
                {
                    if (errors.Any())
                    {
                        errors.Insert(0, $"{tp.Name}");
                        return errors;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                })(),
```

Is there a way I can do this with a ternary? Or a neater way? With a ternary I can't do something like `List.Insert(T)` because it returns void and not the list.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can write an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

```
public static class ListExtensions {
    public static InsertAndReturnSelf<T>(this List<T> source, T item){
        source.Insert(0, item);
        return source;
    }
}
```

then you can do

```
Errors = errors.Any() ? errors.InsertAndReturnSelf($"{testCastStep.Name}") : null;
```

Certainly it would be nice if the standard library had a more [fluent interface](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640997/Fluent-interfaces-and-Method-Chaining-in-Csharp)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, inserting an item into a list returns void, not the list. What you can do, is return a new list instead:

```
var existinglist = new List<string> { "three", "one", "five" };

var condition = true;

var resultList = condition ? new[] { "owl" }.Concat(existinglist).ToList() : existinglist;
```